# Data Communication between Unity and NativeiOS over Realm?

Tags: swift, database, unity-game-engine, realm, pencilkit

I am working on an app that uses a native iOS as a base to show a 3D Room in Unity. I archive this by using:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary-iOS.html

I want to use iOS native because of the pencilKit support.

I am now looking for the best option to share data between the two instances. I am not sure if the better way is to just let the native Swift App talk to a Realm and just send in the data I want to store from Unity to Swift, or if its possible to let both "processes" talk to the same database.

The goal is to create a 3D Object in Unity (that has some properties like coordinates) and assign a PKDrawingFile to it.

Thank you for all your help, Jakob

Comment: There's really no way for us to tell you what the 'best option' is without understanding the entire use case. It's a kind of open ended question and those types of questions are generally not a good fit for SO. This is a coding specific site; Are you having a coding issue? If so, please include your code so we can take a look!